# How to output "&" from jspx?

Tags: java, jsp, jspx

How can the below element be output from [jspx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jspx)?

```
**&nsp;** , output space in jspx
**if(a && a!=b)**, JavaScript file in jspx
```

Comment: what did you try, how it didn't work?

Comment: you need to use html encode(i dont know exact function name in java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `"&amp;"`, e.g.

```
"if(a &amp;&amp; a!=b)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put JavaScript code in its own `.js` file and import it in the HTML using the `<script>` tag.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your javascript in:

```
<![CDATA[

]]>
```